# Create folders and subfolders from excel data using java

Tags: java, excel

Read  from a excel file and based on that data here the excel sheet looks like:

```
Parent_folder    Sub_Folder1   Sub_folder2
University         Department  Faculty
                   Months

Test               Types
```

From the excel file how can i generate directory using java?

Comment: What have you got so far ?

Comment: I can read excel file but i can't make the the cell into directory

Comment: Please provide more details. It looks like you're asking us to write your code

Comment: i developed code to read excel file. but can not make directory and sub directory for example university and department. how can i do this make every cell into directory and subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it.

Read from excel and put it into a string. Append drive name or any other directory you want to add to it (say dirName).

So,

```
  String dirName = <Your directory name with the folder name you fetch from the excel>
  new File(dirName).mkdir();
```